# How to find out port (nat assigned) from which a connection to a web server is made

Tags: php, html, port, traversal, nat

Basically I have access to a Apache server and I want to make a NAT traversal application. I have thought about randomly trying ports on both sides but, quickly discarded that idea. I don't have the ability to run my software on the server, or open any ports, but Apache settings could be changed.

Now my question: Is there any way for a web server to detect from which point is incoming connection being sent? I know that the web server must keep it in memory in order to send the generated html to the proper ip and port otherwise the NAT system would break http. But how do I get the port? I am thinking some logging option but I can't find anything usefull. Or perhaps a php function...

Comment: You should draw an imagine where you locate your webserver and NAT for your question. NAT can be everywhere.

Comment: User (www request - port 80) -> his NAT (port random) -> public web server

and I need to find out the random port

Comment: NAT is at USERS switch, and you are at the webserver machine?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Php/Development/Remoteport.htm

Comment: This returns as a null. Is there a config which disables/enables that functionality in a webserver?

Comment: @hakre let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1380/discussion-between-cz-david-and-hakre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`, which'd be the port the user's NAT gateway is connecting from. Similarly, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will the user's gateway's IP.